# удаление дубликатов из одной колонки в файле excel по условию данных в другой колонке

Tags: excel

Есть такая ситуация в файле 2 записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно почистить дубликаты в isin_code - оставить из дубликатов те, где в колонке sec_code значение имеет суфикс -RM.

подскажите пожалуйста формулу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свободный столбец вписать формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЕТЕСЛИ(A:A;A2)>1;C3="ZYNE-RM")
```

Если перед суффиксом могут быть разные наборы символов, сравнивать только с суффиксом:

```
ПРАВБ(C3,3)="-RM"
```

Установить автофильтр (доп. столбец тоже в фильтре), фильтровать по доп. столбцу по значению `ИСТИНА`.

Копировать фильтрованный диапазон, вставить на другой лист. Или вставить на этот же лист, ниже данных. Исходники удалить.